# Orange Hrm 3.1- adding new menu title to tab

Tags: symfony-1.4, orangehrm

i m new to symfony framework , i m using orangehrm-3.1.1 i have added a new menu title in the second level tab , but i dont know how to navigate to the particualar href link. Please help me out with the steps.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I add menu item via database.

To add a menu in orangehrm there are 3 tables you should check:

- ohrm_screen
- ohrm_menu_item (the menu hierarchy)
- ohrm_user_role_screen (the user role permissions to specific screen)

First, add your link into `ohrm_screen`, specify your `module_id` and `action_url` (Check the module_id in `ohrm_module`).

After that add the screen into `ohrm_menu_item` table.

And then add new record in `ohrm_user_role_screen` with the allowed `user_role_id` and your `screen_id`, the `can_read` field should be 1 (true)

And finally try re-login to your application

Hope you can understand my messy english. :p

Comment: Hi, I want to know how to add a menu which will open a different link(Ex: stackoverflow.com) in a new tab. If I add a link in action_url column in ohrm_screen, the framework automatically appends it own base_url.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you want the answer for your question still now. But I have solution for your question and for everyone who wants to add new tab in the orange HRM. Orange HRM is built in symfony framework, so without solid understanding of symfony framework it is difficult to change anything in orange HRM.
Go to the file-/orangehrm3.1.1/symfony/plugins/orangehrmCorePlugin/lib/authorization/service/MenuService.php
  In this file you will find the main menu service .

Then go to the orangehrm database you will find ohrm_menu_item table and add the name of the menu you want to display.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Check in which module do you want to add your menu
        module list is in ohrm_module table.

Step 2: Check under what user roll you want to add menu
        user roll is in ohrm_user_role.

Step 3: Add Screen on bases of module (step 1)
        insert data into ohrm_screen

step 4: Add Menu Item on bases of Screen (step 3)
        insert into ohrm_menu_item

Step 5: Assign screen to user on bases of user roll (step 2) and screen (step 3)
        insert into ohrm_user_role_screen

Step 6: Logout and login again. New menu will be there.

That's all

Comment: Hi, I want to know how to add a menu which will open a different link(Ex: stackoverflow.com) in a new tab. If I add a link in action_url column in ohrm_screen, the framework automatically appends it own base_url.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the approach mentioned on this [page](http://forum.orangehrm.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13609&sid=8b0c2e0e2e53f0d39aa577c582100ec8).