# How to enable a new Tab in OrangeHRM?

Tags: symfony1, orangehrm

I want to create a new tab in OrangeHRM to add some facility to get customized reports.
I followed the steps in the website
http://vizteck.com/blog/6-steps-how-write-new-module-orange-hrm/
and managed to set up and display a new tab.
Now when I try to write some code in the newly created tab. I get an Error that the tab is not enabled.

Can anyone help me on How to enable this tab?

Answer (score 0):

what version of orangehrm you use?

if you 3.1 versions , can read:
[Orange Hrm 3.1- adding new menu title to tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605786/orange-hrm-3-1-adding-new-menu-title-to-tab)

i use 3.3 version, and name of tables is others ( ohrm_data_group, ohrm_data_group_screen, and others.)

actually i try it whit 3.3 versions.

sorry for the bad english.

Cesar Luis (dantrix2006[at]gmail.com